# how to make jquery get the image source

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make jquery get the image source.

My html code :

```
<img class="img" src="photo src">
```

My jquery code :

```
$("<a href='i want to get the photo source in here' download>download</a>").appendTo('.img');
```

note : the html code is running outside the script tag

Answer (score 0):

this code return full image address

```
<img src="../images/pic.png" />

$('img')[0].src //return https://stackoverflow.com/images/pic.png

$('img').attr('src') //return ../images/pic.png
```